How to display build duration in post-build email notifications in Jenkins for a Maven project?
I’m working on a Jenkins Maven project, and I need to include the time taken for the build to complete in the post-build email notification. However, I couldn’t find any Jenkins-defined environment variables or related plugins that provide this information directly.
I tried implementing a solution using a shell script, but it didn’t work as expected.
Is there any alternative approach to achieve this in Jenkins? Specifically, I want to calculate the build duration (in minutes and seconds) and include it in the email content sent after the build completes.
Here are some things I’ve already tried:
Checked for environment variables that might store the build duration—no luck.
Looked into existing plugins that might help—couldn’t find any suitable ones.
Attempted to calculate the time using a shell script, but the results were inconsistent.
I need to execute this as a Jenkins freestyle project and not as a pipeline project
Any suggestions or code snippets that could help me achieve this on Jenkins Maven Project?

You can capture build duration using the currentBuild variable.
post {
  always {
    script {
      // Calculate the build duration in a readable format
      def durationMillis = currentBuild.duration
      def durationSecs = (durationMillis / 1000) % 60
      def durationMins = (durationMillis / (1000 * 60)) % 60
      def durationHours = (durationMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24
      def durationString = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", durationHours, durationMins, durationSecs)

      // Send email notification
      emailext (
        to: 'recipient@example.com',
        subject: "Build ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName} - ${currentBuild.currentResult}",
        body: """\
        Hi,

        The build ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName} has completed.

        Result: ${currentBuild.currentResult}
        Duration: ${durationString}

        Check the build details here: ${env.BUILD_URL}

        Regards,
        Jenkins
        """
      )
    }
  }
}


Hi, thank you so much but i am specifically trying to execute this as a freestyle project
